# connection error in db controller -php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have file named `dbcontroller.php`. This file is an old file with `mysql` functions. But now i am trying to convert it into `mysqli` functions. Everything is working fine but `$conn` in `mysqli_connect($conn,$query)` is giving an error. How to resolve this?

**Code**

```
class DBController {
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $user = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $database = "stores";

    /**
     * DBController constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }

    function connectDB() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
        return $conn;
    }

    function selectDB($conn) {
        mysqli_select_db($conn,$this->database);
    }

    function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);// error
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($conn,$query);// error
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the error msg say?

Comment: conn is not accesed in other functions or pages.

Comment: ah make $conn a public var with no default variables, then in your __construct assign $this->conn to the connectDB function and see what happens :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is here:

```
public function __construct() {
        $conn = $this->connectDB();
        if(!empty($conn)) {
            $this->selectDB($conn);
        }
    }
```

here `$conn` must be a class variable defined with other variables and can be accessed like:

```
$this->conn
```

Comment: i didn't get it

Comment: make $conn a public var with no default variables, then in your __construct assign $this->conn to the connectDB function